# Using an array as the text content

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I am trying to create a system to place a the values of the array into the text.

Array:

```
var records = [
    ['C', 'Descript']
    ['D', 'Test']
];
```

Creates the 'th' that I want to put the array values in.

```
let newColItem = document.createElement('th');
```

What I have tried:

```
galleryheader.textContent = records[i,1];
```

The i is from a for loop. No values a showing in the galleryheader cell. I can't find anything on how to put the array inside on the web, anyone got some idea of what to do.

All code if you need it:

```
const gallery_table = document.getElementById("gallery_table");
let list = ["A", "B"];
var idName = "";
var records = [
    ['C', 'Descript']
    ['D', 'Test']
];

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        var newRowItem = document.createElement("tr");
        idName = "newRowItem";
        idName = idName.concat(i);
        newRowItem.setAttribute("id", idName);
        gallery_table.appendChild(newRowItem);
    }
    let newColItem = document.createElement('th');
    let galleryheader = document.createElement('h3');
    newColItem.setAttribute("class", i);    
    newRowItem.appendChild(newColItem);
    newColItem.appendChild(galleryheader);
    galleryheader.textContent = records[i,1];


    const element = document.getElementById(idName);
    let nodes = element.getElementsByClassName(i);
    for (let j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
        nodes[j].style.padding = "2px";
        nodes[j].style.width = "33%";
        nodes[j].style.border = "1px solid black";
    }
}
```

Comment: `records[i,1]` should be `records[i][1]`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I tried that, didn't work

Comment: It should work. Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: I recommend you use an array of objects instead of a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @Barmar is that like: var x = { "a":[] };

Comment: `var records = [{x: 'C', y: 'Descript'}, {x: 'D', y: 'Test'}]`. Then you use `records[i].y`. Of course, you should use more meaningful property names than `x` and `y`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks so much, that worked, now I just have to figure out how to grow that objects automatically to work with a database, what fun.

Comment: Your loop and the `if ( i % 3 === 0 )` makes no sense. `newRowItem` is defined inside the `if` statement but anyways you use that variable outside of that if statement.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It is to make a new row after 3 columns are made.

Comment: I know what's for. I was not talking about what is it for. But how do you reference an `undefined` variable every once in a while? `newRowItem.appendChild(newColItem);` being actually `undefined.appendChild(newColItem); // error`